# How to export Azure Machine Learning output to CSV

Tags: excel, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an Azure ML experiment which will give the output as predicted probability values and some charts such as bar chart, pie chart, etc. Now I am able to see the outputs in Azure ML's output page.

How can I export my Azure ML experiment results to CSV (or any other similar format)?

Answer (score 2):

You can just configure that by using the modules under Data Format Conversions. Have a look [here](http://by%20using%20the%20modules%20under%20Data%20Format%20Conversions) and [here](http://studiohelp.azurewebsites.net/Content/html/D1293C4F-5629-4EEF-90A4-097AF6945ED6.htm). Documentation is in progress, unluckily.

Comment: The first link is broken. Can you fix that?

Comment: Thanks. But I want to store it in my local disk. Also I need to store the charts also.

Comment: When I try using Convert to CSV, it is working properly for numerical data which we are getting from Result Dataset port. But when I try for R Device, it is storing it as JSON. I need that image in excel file. How to do this?

Comment: You could certainly parse that, but i am sorry, i have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've trained your model, [publish](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-walkthrough-5-publish-web-service/) it as a web service.  Then from published service, you can [Download Excel Workbook](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consuming-from-excel/).  Through this workbook, it will run your web service with the data you input into excel.  Then it will show the predicted values.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add a module called convert to csv in your experiment.
The Run selected module.

Right click after the module is run and click on 'Download'